# Need help with a Float problem in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css-float

Here is my [site](http://www.logicpkg.com).

The top NAV links look great in Safari, etc, but they all stack in IE. I need help to find a fix.  Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
.container {
width: 560px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: right;
}
ul#nav {
width: 560px;
height: 44px;
margin: 29px 0px 0px 0px;
display: inline;
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
}
ul#nav li {
padding-left: 0;
height: 44px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10060;
}
ul#nav li, ul#nav li a {
display: block;
height: 44px;
float: right;
margin-left: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Better question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @dcestari: The `display:inline` is ignored on floating elements, as they are always block elements. It's commonly used like that to trigger certain non-standard properties in earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float:right;` on the links.